# In R, how do I convert a field in a table from one type to another

Tags: r, format

I have a table with these four fields:

```
item_size: numeric format #
gl_code: string
size_dimension: numeric in scientific notation
quantity: number format #.#
```

I want to convert the formats so it's like this:

```
item_size: numeric format #
gl_code: string
size_dimension: format #.###
quantity: number format #
```

Any advice?

Comment: If your numbers are really numbers (what is the result of `str` on your data?), you can use `sprintf` to format them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use format to set the precision of your number:

```
> f<-2.1212121546546546546
> format(f,3)
[1] "2.121"
```

You could create a function that apply the formating you want and use lapply over your list:

```
> l<-c(1,2,3,4)
> my_format<- function(x) { format(x,3)}
> apply(l,my_format)
[1] "1" "2" "3" "4"
```

More detail on format here :http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/tutoR/html/format.html

Comment: 1) I think you mean sapply. apply requires a margin over which to apply the function, while sapply ("simple" apply) returns a vector when given a vector input. 2) You shouldn't have to apply your function at all – format is vectorized: format(l, 3)

Comment: `sapply` is not "simple apply", but rather lapply followed by simplify (for details, see docs)